# Accessing Page From App?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am only just starting out with iPhone application development and have been doing some research with regards at getting data into an app using information available via the web.

I understand that I can access web pages using the NSURL* classes. Does anyone know how I might request data from a page that requires user input?

I can understand accessing an actual page, but I am not sure if (or how) I might be able to initiate the request and get the appropriate data back into my app.

Any help / pointers is very much appreciated.

## EDIT_001:

I was thinking that I would have to interact with the actual controls on the page, but after a little more investigation I have found that I can simply use the request HTML that the page generates.

gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really too broad ("how does http networking work"), and if you look around this site you will probably find several questions that will take you in the right direction. As a first stop, check out the [ASIHTTPRequest framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). Many people use it, and it makes http networking really simple.

You could also have a look at these links for inspiration:

http://iphoneonrails.com/
http://metaskills.net/2010/2/12/synchronizing-core-data-with-rails-3-0-0-pre

Comment: Thank you, I think from what I have found and the ideas from your goodself I now know the rough direction I should be going. Much appreciated.