# Objective C - get response from php file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have some php files in a server which generate xml code in them.

I need to get this xml code from an Iphone app by sending some GET parameters to the files.

For instance http://myserver.com/myFile.php?param=xxxx
and then get the xml generated in this file.

I have been researching a lot but couldn´t get any results yet.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple request, you could use `stringWithContentsOfURL`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

A very similar question [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292688/accessing-page-from-app/):

Please read (or re-read) [the SO faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). Questions should be

> ```
> * detailed and specific
> * written clearly and simply
> * of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere
> ```

And:

> Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!)